# SQL query to take top N number of rows, but should include atleast one row from each groups based on a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL table like this

```
ID         JobZone        Title       
-------------------------------
1            1             Job1
2            1             Job2
3            1             Job3
4            1             Job4
5            2             Job5
6            2             Job6
7            2             Job7
8            2             Job8
9            3             Job9
10           3             Job10
11           4             Job11
12           4             Job12
13           5             Job13
14           4             Job14
15           5             Job15
16           6             Job16
17           7             Job17
18           7             Job18
19           7             Job19
20           8             Job20
```

I need to select top 2 rows from all jobzones. Means it should include at least 1 rows from every jobzones if there is no 2 rows per jobzones.

How can I make it possible?

I tried

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobZone ORDER BY title) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```

Also I tried `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()` which also did not work as I expected.

So the result should be something like this

```
ID         JobZone        Title       
-------------------------------
1            1             Job1
2            1             Job2
5            2             Job5
6            2             Job6
9            3             Job9
10           3             Job10
11           4             Job11
12           4             Job12
13           5             Job13
15           5             Job15
16           6             Job16
17           7             Job17
18           7             Job18
20           8             Job20
```

Comment: Please show your expected results.  I'm having difficulty understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Siyual I just edited the question to include the expected result

Comment: well, of course, you are using `WHERE rn = 1` and it seems that you want `WHERE RN <= 2`

Comment: No criterias, just order by title the top from each zones. But 2 rows should be there if more than 2 rows under that zone

Comment: So if `N = 2` and there is 5 groups, you return 5 rows? But if `N = 10` and there are two groups, you return up to 5 rows for group? or maybe 2 and 8 if one group is too small?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the top 2 of each job zone, you just need to change your `WHERE`:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobZone ORDER BY title) AS rn
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
```

For your scenario, you already have the `ROW_NUMBER` correct. Here's a quick breakdown of the 3 usual choices:

- ROW_NUMBER - Assigns unique numbers to each row within the partition in the sequence of your order clause ({10, 10, 20} would ROW_NUMBER to {1, 2, 3})
- RANK - Assigns unique numbers to each unique value leaving gaps for rows that have the same value (ie: {10, 10, 20} would RANK to {1, 1, 3})
- DENSE_RANK - Same as RANK except no gaps are left ({10, 10, 20} would DENSE_RANK to {1, 1, 2})

Answer (score 0):

It's already answered, but I wrote some code to verify the solution above creating a temp table

```
CREATE TABLE #test
(
    ID int not null, 
    jobzone int not null, 
    title varchar(100) not null
)

INSERT INTO #test
SELECT 1, 1, 'Job1'
UNION
SELECT 2, 1, 'Job2'
UNION
SELECT 3, 1, 'Job3'
UNION
SELECT 4, 1, 'Job4'
UNION
SELECT 5, 2, 'Job5'
UNION
SELECT 6, 2, 'Job6'
UNION
SELECT 7, 2, 'Job7'
UNION
SELECT 8, 2, 'Job8'
UNION
SELECT 9, 3, 'Job9'
UNION
SELECT 10, 3, 'Job10'
UNION
SELECT 11, 4, 'Job11'
UNION
SELECT 12, 4, 'Job12'
UNION
SELECT 13, 5, 'Job13'
UNION
SELECT 14, 4, 'Job14'
UNION
SELECT 15, 5, 'Job15'
UNION
SELECT 16, 6, 'Job16'
UNION
SELECT 17, 7, 'Job17'
UNION
SELECT 18, 7, 'Job18'
UNION
SELECT 19, 7, 'Job19'
UNION
SELECT 20, 8, 'Job20'

select *
from #test

;WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY JobZone ORDER BY title) AS rn
   FROM #test
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 2
```